# QGIS Custom Symbols Group File Location

Tags: qgis, symbology, group-layer

I am curious as to the location of the symbols group files. I have created numerous custom symbols, as well as symbol groups.

I would like to share these with the people I work with.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things you can do:

- Create a "svg" folder in your `/Users/your_username/.qgis2/`
- You can find the location of the SVG symbols location by hovering your mouse cursor over the SVG Groups folder in the *Styles* options of a layer and selecing **SVG fill**:

[image: Properties]

- You can set the path yourself in QGIS via *Settings*  > *Options*:

[image: SVG Path]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank You Joseph!

What I finally figured out was to export an XML file from the Style Manager, I was then able to import it to the other systems. It took a few minutes to understand what I was doing, but the procedure was really simple, and easily remembered after you do it once.

Comment: Awesome buddy! You should post your solution as an answer (and accept it after a couple of days) as others could find it useful.